# Convert large SQL Server database to MySQL database

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database-migration

I am trying to migrate a SQL Server database to a MySQL database.

I tried doing same using MySQL Workbench but for some driver related reasons, I am unable to have it work for me.

I also tried online converter tool , http://www.sqlines.com/online

This works fine but I have to manually copy paste 5000 lines every time and convert and again do for next 5000 lines. This is too tedious as my SQL Server database is approx 10GB. Also text editors crash while opening this huge SQL Server file containing exported data.

I need smarter and accurate way possible.
Please help. Thank you.

Comment: What's the problem with the workbenches?

Comment: Driver related issue. It might work on windows but i am working on Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Please post your error log for analysis.

Comment: Ok Sure. I will get the logs and share.